# What is the equivalent type ElasticSearch "keyword" in Bigquery?

Tags: elasticsearch, types, google-bigquery

I would like to load data from BigQuery to ElasticSearch using these custom mappings.

```html
{
  "properties": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "affordable": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "building_type": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "category_1_name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "category_2_name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "category_3_name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "company_id": {
      "type": "long"
    }
 }
```

I'm not sure what is the equivalent type for "keyword" that i can use in BigQuery. Appreciate your help! Thanks

Comment: Could you give a little bit more detail why you need a equivalent type for keyword on BigQuery?

Comment: BTW, this is a just question. There is no direct equivalent. `keyword` is used for structured content such as IDs, email addresses, hostnames, status codes, zip codes, or tags. On BigQuery side, there is a string for this type of data. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#string_type

Comment: could you give detail about what keyword type represents in elasticsearch?